# uninitialized constant Mechanize when using mechanize gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to use mechanize for web scraping, but it already gives me an error in the beginning.

```
require 'rubygems'
require "mechanize"

agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

page = agent.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')

searchForm = page.form(:action => '//www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php')
```

The error looks like

```
C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/proj/mechanize.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mechanize (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/proj/mechanize.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How can I fix the error?

Comment: have you installed mechanize?

Comment: have you restart your serv after installing?

Comment: Try renaming your file to something other than `mechanize.rb`